# ASP.NET MVC HtmlDecode WebGrid Column

Tags: asp.net-mvc, webgrid

I want to use System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode with WebGrid but it is not working
my code is :

```
grid.GetHtml(tableStyle: "webGrid",
             htmlAttributes: new { id = "DataTable" },
             headerStyle: "header",
             alternatingRowStyle: "alt",
             columns: grid.Columns(
                 grid.Column("ArtId"),
                 grid.Column(columnName: "ArtDescription",
                                         format: item => System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(item.ArtDescription))
             )
 )
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use [Html.Raw](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg568896%28v=vs.111%29.aspx):

```
format: item => Html.Raw(item.ArtDescription)
```